# Java - Passing an array directly into the constructor, not as a variable

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, arguments

Let's take the following example:

```
public class Test {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        int[] someInts = {1, 2, 5};
        new Dummy(1, someInts, "Hello");    //works
        new Dummy(1, new int[] {1, 2, 5}, "Hello"); //works
        new Dummy(1, {1, 2, 5}, "Hello");   //fails
        new Dummy(1, [1, 2, 5], "Hello");   //fails
    }

    public class Dummy {
        Dummy(int someNumber, int[] someArray, String message) {

        }
    }
}
```

For both failing lines, Eclipse says: *"The constructor Test.Dummy(int, int, int, int, String) is undefined"*

Firstly, I don't understand why it doesn't recognize the array as an array (in the failing lines only).

Secondly, why can I not pass the array directly into the constructor, but instead have to create a variable to pass it?

And thirdly, is there a way to create a constructor which takes something like that line in question, meaning without a variable or a `new int[] {...}` statement?

If someone knows a better way to formulate this in the title, feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, that's how you create an array literal in the general case.

You could replace the array with a `int... array` varargs parameter, but then you'll need to make it the last parameter.

```
Dummy(int someNumber, String message, int... someArray) {}
new Dummy(1, "Hello", 1, 2, 5);
```

Comment: I also know that syntax, but that's not what I am searching for.

Comment: Then explain yourself better. Do you expect us to both give you free advice **and** read your mind?

Comment: _"is there a way to create a constructor which takes something like that line in question, meaning without a variable or a new int[] {...} statement?"_ That's what it says in my question and that's what I'm looking for. Is there a way or is the shortest way really to make the `new` statement inline?

Comment: Well I provided the shortest possible way, since it's still an array, but the compiler just handles the syntax.

Comment: Well, technically he did. But the thing is that my constructor takes three arrays of the same kind while Kayaman's solution unfortunately only works if there was only one.

Comment: @jaySon maybe you should then complain to Oracle that they don't give you the syntax you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

`new Dummy(1, {1, 2, 5}, "Hello");`, you can only use `{}` syntax for array initialization .  use `new Dummy(1,new int[] {1, 2, 5}, "Hello");`